# How to make background around header with opacity, while header is transparent?

Tags: css

I know how to make background with opacity, and to make header transparent. 
However, I have put image as the background, and I want to be with 50% opacity around the header, because I want my header to be transparent, and to have clear view part of background image.
So far, i have input img background, and set up header with 50% opacity, but I need to be opposite. If i put background transparent, it will be even in the header, so it doesn't work for me.

Please does anyone know how to do it?

it should look like this 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/lb4xi6s9rjaa4lw/unnamed.png

Please ask me if you need additional explanation of the issue.

Comment: can you show your code .. what have you done so far... & it would be great if its on fiddle.

Comment: What is your overall body background ? white?

Comment: First half of the page (from top) is the image, and the rest is white.   http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_UtQyNOQGaVM/TU_uyyVyyqI/AAAAAAAADew/-lNWZBomTec/s1600/transparent+element.png  this is just an example what I have now, but I want to be opposite, the image to have opacity while  the container to have transparent, and clear view. I would like to upload img what I have so far, but I am not able since I dont have 10 reputation. (I have similar to this link that I post, except that container I have header. )

Comment: @user3042036 is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/LdR29/5/

Comment: @KingKing It is not exactly, because I need a entire header to be transparent, and the background picture to be transparent. It should look like this https://www.dropbox.com/s/lb4xi6s9rjaa4lw/unnamed.png

Comment: @user3042036 try this http://jsfiddle.net/LdR29/9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some things CSS cannot do (or I cannot do with CSS) and this case is one of them. If you want this to work, you will need to use some scripting (and , unfortunately, math).  Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="picture"></div>
<div id="overlay-left"></div>
<div id="overlay-right"></div>
<header>Lorem ipsum</header>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
header {
    border-top: 120px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -480px;
    width:960px;
    height: 400px;
    z-index: 100;
    color: white;
}
#picture {
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    height: 400px;
    width: 100%;
    background: url("yourbackground.png");
}
#overlay-left {
    left:0;
    height: 400px;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0.5;
    background-color: white;
    z-index:100;
}
#overlay-right {
    right:0;
    height: 400px;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0.5;
    background-color: white;
    z-index:100;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready( function() {
 var widtha = ($(window).width() - 960)/2 ; //960 is the width of the box

 $('#overlay-left').css('width' , widtha + "px");
  $('#overlay-right').css('width' , widtha + "px");

});
```

The jQuery helps the CSS decide how much should it cover in order to make a nice box in the middle of a background image. This is responsive and it will always stay in the center as long as the viewport width is above 960. The math part is that the Jquery takes the viewport width, subtracts the width of the box and divides it into two parts - left and right. Then you just tell jquery to put the value in the CSS.

Try it out , hope it helps. I'll put a JS fiddle if you need one.